# Как подключить svg спрайт в файл в html и css

Tags: html, css, html5, svg, svg-спрайт

Есть сгенерированый `svg` спрайт - **sprite.svg** c `symbol`:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;">
            <symbol viewBox="0 0 10 10" id="user"> ...
```

Если вставлять прямо в `html`, то все подключается отлично -

```
<svg class="icon-box">
  <use xlink:href="#user"></use>
</svg>
```

Но если подключать из файла (т.е. когда **sprite.svg** лежит в images) , то не отображается:

```
<svg class="icon-box">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#user"></use>
</svg>
```

**Почему не отображается иконка и как подключить в стили css иконку из спрайта?**

Answer (score 5):

Как правило решение проблем с отображением иконок из спрайта можно разделить  на три части:

1. **Код иконок и спрайта**, - так как вы их не включили  в вопрос, трудно
   сказать что-то определенное. Надеюсь вы добавите коды хотя-бы одной
   иконки и части спрайта.
2. **Подключение файла спрайта.**
3. **Подключение внешней таблицы стилей** и стилизация самих иконок.

   ---

   ### Подключение файла спрайта

При подключении файла спрайта через тег `<img>`и `background-image` внешняя таблица стилей не будет работать, поэтому лучше подключать через тег `<object>`

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="sprite.svg" >
  Your browser does not support SVG
</object>
```

Сам файл спрайта необходимо разместить в одной папке с `Index file` особенно браузер `Chrome` чувствителен к этому. 
При вызове отдельной иконки из файла спрайта добавьте еще namespace SVG и внутреннюю таблицу стилей svg

```
<svg class="icon-box" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#user"></use>
</svg>
```

Может это излишне для некоторых браузеров, но вы же наверное хотите кроссбраузерное решение.

Тег `<object>` добавления файла спрайта в HTML необходимо разместить в листинге выше вызовов иконок, лучше в хедере. Это понятно,  иконки должны загрузиться до вызова их в конкретном месте странички.

### Подключение внешней таблицы стилей

В шапке файла спрайта необходимо добавить путь до внешней таблицы стилей

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Svgstyle.css"?>   
<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
Код спрайта 
</svg>
```

Можно сделать специально для svg внешний файл стилей `Svgstyle.css` и разместить его в той же папке, что и `index` файл и затем подключить его к главной таблице стилей.

**UPD 19.05.2017**

Подключение с помощью `background-image`

```css
.wrapperSvgImage {
  background-image: url(http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 82px;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapperSvgImage"></div>
```

[Пример  из источника](https://css-tricks.com)

Comment: так а в css можно как-то подключить иконку из спрайта?

Comment: @hug можно подключить, через background-image, но это не лучший путь. Выше про это написано и вот ещё можно почитать про способы подключения  https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047#inline-p   Попробуйте всё сделать, как в ответе написано и у вас всё получится

Comment: так в ответе и не видно как из спрайта взять опр. картинку и включить ее в css фоном иконки, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @hug я отвечал исключительно по вашим кодам в вопросе. Вы всё правильно делали, но ведь не сработало. Значит причина в чем-то другом. Вот это другое, что помогло помешать я и проанализировал в своем ответе. Я просил привести коды иконки и код части спрайта, там тоже часто бывают проблемы.

Comment: `background-image: url("img/_sprite/sprite.svg");` подключение через css

Comment: #user bacground-position потом подогнать?

Comment: @hug я не использую `background-image` для подключения svg из-за его недостатков, есть много других хороших способов подключения Если у вас есть желание сделать именно через  `background-image` посмотрите здесь в выборке вопросов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsvg%5Dbackground-image

Comment: ответ хороший но ничем не помог, ваш способ подключения в цсс вообще не о том. с инлайн что-то тоже не работает ну видимо из-за того что хром

Answer (score 0):

- Через тег `<img>`
- CSS  `background: url(путь);`
- Да много способов - гугл их все знает))

Comment: Вот здесь интересная статья [ТЫК](https://svgontheweb.com/ru/)